# Does light propagate at the speed of light in curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, causality

There seems to be a lot of different ways to consider how one can describe electromagnetic waves in curved spacetime, and whether or not they go "at the speed of light" seems to be somewhat of a complicated statement :

- Given a test EM field in an arbitrary metric, the WKB approximation of the field may not have a null wavevector $k$[[1]](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/19636/1/CQG_waves_accepted.pdf)[[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06572.pdf), so that $|k| \neq 0$.
- For an exactly solvable Einstein-Maxwell system, a system is called null if $\|F\| = 0$ and $\star F \wedge F = 0$, and non-null otherwise. By the Mariot-Robinson theorem[[3]](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31909/f2055.item)[[4]](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1703712), a null system can be associated with a null geodesic congruence, which is usually interpreted as photon paths, but there exists exact solutions which are non-null[[5]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/exact-solutions-of-einsteins-field-equations/11CF6CFCC10CC62B9B299F08C32C37A6).
- If we consider the Green's function of an electromagnetic field in curved spacetime, it can be decomposed (in [Hadamard form](https://archive.org/details/lecturesoncauchy00hadauoft)) into a singular part which lives entirely on the lightcone, and a tail term, which is inside the light cone, corresponding to parts of the field arriving later[[6]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491660900300?via%3Dihub). DeWitt hints at possible scenarios where the singular part may not carry any part of the field, but no details are included.
- The propagation of discontinuities of the EM field happens on the null characteristic surfaces of the wave equation[[7]](https://www.cambridge.org/fr/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/wave-equation-curved-space-time?format=PB&isbn=9780521136365).

From [[8]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S000349168371050X), it seems that all those notions are somewhat related, but not entirely trivially. Things are also generally complicated by the different case of test fields versus test fields with backreaction versus exact solutions, since the actual light cone will be that of the exact solution.

The question being, what can we say about the general case? Are we guaranteed that the propagation of an EM wave (perhaps a compactly supported one) occurs at least in part on the light cone, or are there scenarios in which this does not occur? And is the field on the light cone related to the geometric optic limit, for $\omega \to \infty$?

Comment: This paper may help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04222

Comment: I think the variety of different approaches and theorems is telling us that the problem is defining a wave in curved spacetime in the first place. If you have just some tensor field $F_{\mu\nu}(x)$, what is the wave speed? It's a concept that only makes sense for particular field configurations.